# Voice coding in Emacs on Mac OS X

Tags: emacs, voice-recognition, naturallyspeaking

I would like to be able to write code by voice recognition and him currently using Aquamacs 2.4  and Dragon Dictate 2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8. Does anybody know if this is possible and if so how? I've seen shorttalk, emacs listen, and voice code but they only work on windows machines with Dragon Naturally Speaking.

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Also I am writing in R via ESS.

Comment: What do you want to do that you can't do now?

Comment: Dragon Dictate comes with the ability to create custom commands, which is pretty powerful.  I'm working on creating a small DSL that will be used to export command files to be imported into Dragon Dictate 3.  And another project to extend the functionality of Dragon Dictate custom commands. https://github.com/siderakis/dragon-fire

Comment: I don't think Dragon Dictate supports grammars like Dragon NaturallySpeaking does via SAPI.

Comment: @NickSiderakis I like that you're working on dragon-fire, but I didn't see any documentation. Can you talk about what it can And can't do a little?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this presentation by Tavis Rudd : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI

He runs Dragon Naturally Speaking inside a Windows VM, because the Windows version can be scripted with Python. Then the VM communicates with Emacs on his local machine.

He says in the presentation he will open source his code, but it doesn't seem to be there yet on his Github.

So yes, it's possible, but at this point there is no out of the box solution. If you really want this, prepare to invests weeks or months to get to a properly working setup.

Answer (score 3):

I recently released the coding-by-voice solution I created to solve my own RSI issues. It can be found here: http://www.voicecode.io

I use it mostly for coding in Sublime Text and Xcode, but it works great with emacs or vim as well. The great thing about this solution is that all commands can be chained into "command phrases" so you don't have to pause between every individual command like you do with other voice command solutions.

It has builtin support for all standard variable-name formats (snake case, camel case, etc), has builtin commands for every permutation of keyboard shortcuts (ie command-shift-5, command-option-shift-T, and so on), has cursor movement commands, app switching commands, window switching commands, commands for symbol combos like "=>", "||", ">=", etc, and tons more. Plus it is very easy to add your own custom commands as well.